# How to dynamically switch databases at loadtime in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

What I'd like to do is to have two or more WP databses under the same instalation, each with its own posts, and dynamically switch between them at loading time.

For example, instead of directly plugging WP when a visitor loads the site, first run a PHP script for geo-location and based on this script's result to tell WP which database to load up.

I know about switch_blog but I understand it's a backend technique as it's expensive to run on the front-end.

Thanks

Comment: you can use a load balancing server for that WordPress can't do anything

Comment: @ArunKillu, why not? It would need to instruct the main WP php scripts which database to use...only that I'm not that familiar with the WP build, but I know PHP..

Comment: just tweak wp-config.php to switch db depending on whatever you calculate your condition on... sounds like a nightmare to maintain though..

Comment: @Ben , I was thinking about that, but I don't know if it is secure and also, does Wordpress maintain such info in any session file on the server or is it up to me to pass the info so WP knows which user needs which database?

Comment: It's as secure as the code you write. Wordpress doesn't store db settings in any session, the variables are populated on every request

Comment: have you thought about using wordpress multisite?

Comment: @danyo , I documented myself and finally chose to run the MU stack  from BinNami. Thanks